# TToolButton behaviour when checked

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have a `TToolButton` on a `TJvToolBar` which is linked to an action which opens a serial port. I have this code in my action's `OnExecute()` event:

```
procedure TfrmMainForm.acInstrumentConnectedExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if acInstrumentConnected.Checked then
    if MessageDlg('Are you sure you wish to disconnect?', mtWarning, [mbYes, mbNo], 0,
      mbNo) <> mrYes then
      exit;
  acInstrumentConnected.Checked := not acInstrumentConnected.Checked;
  // actual code to connect/disconnect follows...
end;
```

As you see, I change my action's `Checked` after the message box if the user wishes to disconnect from the port, but the ToolButton's `Down` property changes before entering this event. This leads to an `Up` button even if the user chooses *No* in response to the prompt. Why is the ToolButton behaving this way?

Comment: What style is the button `tbsButton` or `tbsCheck`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan tbsButton

Comment: I think you'll have more luck with `tbsCheck`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have no experience with TToolButton's different styles. Does the action get executed with tbsCheck?

Comment: Yes it does. I've always used `tbsCheck` tool buttons for that type of button, one that uses the `Down` state to give visual feedback to the user.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks. tbsCheck + Grouped = True works just fine. Can you please describe this behavior? I've read your other answers, and you always provide useful information about the nature of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a tool button that is used to indicate a boolean state. Such buttons should use the `tbsChecked` tool button style. When the button uses that style, clicking the button toggles its `Down` property.

You are using the `tbsButton` button style. This is for a standard push button that is not meant to indicate state. When you have a `tbsButton`, the `Down` property is always `False` during and after the `OnClick` event.

In addition to setting the style to `tbsChecked` you can set the `Grouped` property to `True`  (keeping `AllowAllUp` as `False`). That will prevent your button from automatic `Down` state switching. You'll be able then to switch the state of your button in the way you've used.